# How to find the limit $ \lim_{x \to 4}{2x-8\sqrt x+8 \over \sqrt x-2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 4}{2x-8\sqrt x+8 \over \sqrt x-2}$

I am not sure where to begin with this problem after I try subbing in 4 and getting 0/0. I would love some help with this problem and would appricaite anything

Comment: @Asimov, that edit is almost surely incorrect.

Comment: Where do you get $0/0$? If you plug in 4, you immediately get the answer no problem.

Comment: He wrote no parentheses @Asimov, yet he said he got a $\;0/0\;$ expression. This means your edit wasn't right and, anyway, why not first ask the OP *before* editing his post?

Comment: @Fujoyaki I think the problem was with Asimov's edit. I corrected it.
For next time, OP, use this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to write your question in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

hints:

$$\frac{2x-8\sqrt x+8}{\sqrt x-2}=2\frac{x-4\sqrt x+4}{\sqrt x-2}=2\frac{(\sqrt x-2)^2}{\sqrt x-2} =\ldots$$

Comment: How did you go from the second step to the third step, I am pretty confused by that

Comment: Binomial formula, @user3261963: $$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$$ with $\;a=\sqrt x\;,\;\;b=2\;$

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the `Lim` actually says, I believe I can answer this by generality.

You say, "I try subbing in 4 and getting 0/0". This is a problem. The limit should be thought of as a variable approaches some number. So, where does your function go to when `x=3`? When `x=3.5`? When `x=3.9`? When `x = 3.9999999....`?

However, this is just for that one direction! We still have to think about the direction of when x is approaching from the other side!

For example: When `x=5`, When `x=4.5`, when `x=4.000...1`.

If these numbers happen to be the same, then we say the limit will equal this same number.

If these numbers are different, then we say that this limit is undefined.